# How to write the data converted from json to csv without skipping the rows

Tags: json, python-3.x, csv

I have converted a json to csv. The issue is the when I'm writing the json content to csv, in the excel the data is coming in alternate lines

The code I have been using is:

```
with open(name_j,'r',encoding='utf8') as data_file:
    data = json.loads(data_file.read())


with open('../json_to_csv/Data/Output/Output.csv', 'w',encoding='utf8') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)

    writer.writerow(['doi', 'is_oa', 'title', 'publisher','z_authors','journal_name' ])
    #writer.writerow(['doi','title', 'publisher','journal_name'])

    for row in data:
        doi = row['doi']
        oa = row['is_oa']
        name = row['title']
        pub = row['publisher']
        author = row['z_authors']
        jName = row['journal_name']

        row = [doi, oa, name, pub, jName]
        #row = [doi, name, pub, jName]

        writer.writerow(row)
```

[Final csv result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akyTu.jpg)
How to write without skipping the rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is a little change in your code:

```
with open('../json_to_csv/Data/Output/Output.csv', 'w',encoding='utf8', newline='') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
```